# Why am I getting White background tabs in VS 2019 Dark Theme?

Tags: visual-studio

When I switched back to my Dark theme on VS from other themes, the tab backgrounds are stuck in white.  Has anyone else had this issue?

[image]

I've restarted VS, disabled all extensions, and even tried signing into different accounts to see if it made a difference, but I can't to seem to get rid of it.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Which filetype, all of them?

Comment: Yes, every single one! :(

Comment: Strange. Don't know how to fix, but in Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors->Text Editor, what does it say for e.g. 'Plain Text' as 'Item Background'? For dark theme that should be a black box labelled 'Default'.

Comment: Ah!! That was it! The options weren't set to Default! Thank you @stijn

Comment: I'd suggest you post that as an answer yourself :)